# python pandas groupby and subtract columns from different groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe df1

```
pid     stat       h1         h2       h3      h4      h5      h6     ...     h20

1        a        3.2        3.5       6.2     7.1    1.2      2.3    ...    3.2
1        b        3.3        1.5       4.2     7.7    4.2      3.5   ...     8.4
1        a        3.1        3.8       2.2     1.1    6.2      5.3   ...     9.2
1        b        3.7        1.2       8.2     4.7    3.2      8.5   ...     2.4
:        :         :          :         :       :      :        :      :      :
2        a        2.2       3.8        6.2     7.3    1.3      4.3   ...     3.2
2        b        4.3       1.3        4.2     5.7    2.2      3.1   ...     2.4
2        a        2.1       3.7        2.4     1.6    6.4      9.3   ...     9.6
2        b        3.8       1.3        8.7     3.7    7.2      8.3   ...     9.4
:        :         :         :          :       :      :        :     :       : 
3        a        2.2       3.8        6.2     7.3     1.3     4.3   ...     3.2
3        b        4.3       1.3        4.2     5.7     2.2     3.1   ...     2.4
3        a        2.1       3.7        2.4     1.6     6.4     9.3   ...     9.6
3        b        3.8       1.3        8.7     3.7     7.2     8.3   ...     9.4
  :      :         :         :          :       :       :        :     :      :
```

I would like to obtain groups indexed on `pid` and `stat` and then subtract `h` values of group1 from `h` values of group2 for a final `dataframe` (`df2`). This final dataframe needs to be reindexed with numbers starting from `0:len(groups)` Repeat it iteratively for all permutations of pid like 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-1, 2-3 ... etc. I need to perform other calculations on the on the final dataframe `df2`(values in the below `df2` are not exact subtracted, but just a representation)

```
pid(string)     stat    h1p1-h1p2   h2p1-h2p2   h3p1-h3p2   h4p1-h4p2   h5p1-h5p2   h6p1-h6p2   ...  h20p1-h2p2

   1-2           a        3.2         3.5         6.2         7.1         1.2         2.3        ...      3.2
   1-2           b        3.3         1.5         4.2         7.7         4.2         3.5        ...      8.4
   1-2           a        3.1         3.8         2.2         1.1         6.2         5.3        ...      9.2
   1-2           b        3.7         1.2         8.2         4.7         3.2         8.5        ...      2.4
   1-3      ....
```

I looked at options of;

```
  for (pid, stat), group in df1.groupby(['pid', 'stat']):
      print('pid  = %s Stat =  %s' %(pid, stat))
      print group
```

this gives me groups but, I am not sure how to access dataframes from this for loop and use it for subtracting from other groups. Also

```
  df_grouped = df.groupby(['pid', 'stat']).groups()
```

still not sure how to access the new dataframe of groups and perform operations. I would like to know, if this can be done using groupby or if there is any better approach. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a generator and ignored the `stat` column because it makes no different in any groups according to your sample. Please tell me if I did it wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import permutations

def subtract_group(df, col):
    pid = df['pid'].unique()

    # select piece with pid == i
    segment = lambda df, i: df[df['pid'] == i].reset_index()[col]

    for x, y in permutations(pid, 2):
        result_df = pd.DataFrame(segment(df, x) - segment(df, y))

        # rename columns
        result_df.columns=["%sp%d-%sp%d" % (c, x, c, y) for c in col]

        # insert pid column
        result_df.insert(0, 'pid', '-'.join([str(x), str(y)]))

        yield result_df
```

You can test it with:

```
# column name in your case
columns = ['h' + str(i+1) for i in range(20)]

print next(subtract_group(df1, columns))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you!